# Creating a table onclick based on database value

Tags: php, jquery, html-table, onclick

I have a little problem. I'm using this tutorial

http://www.codemashups.com/dynamic-search-filtering-using-jquery-and-php/

It allows me to search my database and return the results in a table.
This is the basics of the code in the page "search-data.php"

```
    if ($conn) {

    /* Fetch the users input from the database and put it into a
     valuable $fetch for output to our table. */
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients 
                         WHERE client_name LIKE '%{$param}%' OR client_email REGEXP '^$param'  OR client_address LIKE '%{$param}%' OR client_postcode LIKE '%{$param}%' OR client_phone REGEXP '^$param'");

    /*
       Retrieve results of the query to and build the table.
       We are looping through the $fetch array and populating
       the table rows based on the users input.
     */
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $fetch ) ) {
        $sResults .= '<tr id="'. $row->id . '" >';
        $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->client_name . '</td>';
        $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->client_email . '</td>';
        $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->client_address . '</td>';
        $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->client_postcode . '</td>';
        $sResults .= '<td>' . $row->client_phone . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }

}

/* Free connection resources. */
mysql_close($conn);

/* Toss back the results to populate the table. */
echo $sResults;
```

It all works fine and using my table I can search and it displays the info I want, great you ask! What do you want then?

Well, my table is a stores client information, and in previous none searchable tables I have done, you click on the client you want from the list and you then go to a page of all their info (info in the list is limited to name and address where as the full pages has phone, postcode etc etc) and to do it I use an onclick.

So here is my table for the new searchable table:

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th class="ui-state-default">Name</th>
                    <th class="ui-state-default">Email</th>
                    <th class="ui-state-default">Address</th>
                    <th class="ui-state-default">Postcode</th>
                    <th class="ui-state-default">Phone</th>
                </tr>
            <tbody id="results" onclick="location='../clients.php?action=viewClient&amp;clientId=<?php echo  ?>'" ></tbody>
        </table>
```

Like I said it works great, and all the client info come up, but I need to have the "id" come up in between the echo on the onclick line (I suppose it doesn't need an echo if it shows the right id).

```
onclick="location='../clients.php?action=viewClient&amp;clientId=<?php echo  ?>
```

So can anyone see a easy way to get the information about id into the onclick, I have tried creating an onlick in the `<tr>` part of the "search-data.php" page but it didn't work either because it wont or I did it wrong, the later I'm thinking.

Anyways any help would be great.

--------------------EDIT--------------------------

I have found out that I can create a link that works. I can create the link on the result like this:

```
 $sResults .= '<td><a href="../clients.php?action=viewClient&amp;clientId='. $row->id .'">'. $row->client_name .'</a></td>';
```

This create a working link, but when I try and do a similar thing for the onclick it doesn't even go anywhere let alone the right place, as if it doesn't like doing it that way, If this helps anyone get further with the onclick problem that would be great.

Comment: Did you create a php page that genarate the table?

Comment: You should simply use real links...

Comment: I dont use real links, I have a page called viewClient which is populated dynamically based on the id, so if the id in the link is 8 will show the details for a different user than if it was 1

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jQuery remove the onclick on your table and add the following javascript:

Based on the tutorial, you should need to update the head section of your search page to this and you shouldn't have to update any of your other code for this to work.

```
<head>
    <title>jQuery Search Autocomplete</title>

    <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
        @import "css/grid_sytles.css";
        @import "css/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css";
    </style>

    <!-- jQuery libs -->
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-search.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $('td').click(function() {
                var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                window.location = '../clients.php?action=viewClient&clientId=' + id;
            }
        }(jQuery));
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: I dont know Jquery too much, and still not sure how to get the id from the "search-data.php" page into this.

Comment: The 3rd line is what handles retrieving the ID.  So basically, if any cell is clicked in the table, it goes up to the parent which is the TR tag and looks at the id attribute on that and stores the ID attribute into the variable id and then appends the id to the end of the string to generate the window location.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. sorry for my late reply. Unfortunately I cant get this to work, when i click the row of results it doesn't link anywhere as if its not recognizing the onclick unction in the javascript :(